# YA 'Weird' Short Story Collection - early 80s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

I'm looking for a book of weird/creepy short stories I read in school (UK) around 1980. I guess YA as it was on the curriculum.

I can only really remember that the lead story (illustrated on the front cover) was about a gifted African soccer player playing in a major tournament. He played barefoot and was murdered by jealous rivals who froze the soccer ball, so he died of shock when he kicked it. Then spooky stuff happened, such as snow never settled on his grave, etc.

Stuck in my mind for some reason so would be interested in reviewing it after all these years. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of saying `etc, etc` can you list other 'spooky' things that happened?

Comment: To be honest I couldn't remember any others so used etc etc in  a 'yada yada' kind of way. But will take note and be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[The Ice Warrior](http://www.myrddinsheir.com/warrior.html)" by Robin Chambers is likely the story you're thinking of. It has the barefoot Zaire kicker, the frozen ball, a grave where there was always snow even in summer (I know... a reversal of what you said), and then some other mysterious goings-on such as the people who set up the frozen ball dying in ice-related ways.

It looks like it's only ever been collected in *[The Ice Warrior and Other Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?41894)*.

[image: Book cover] [image: Another cover]

Comment: Spot on my friend! I googled the title and the first image it found is the cover of the edition I remember. Obviously my recollection of some of the details have 'decayed' in the nigh on forty years since I read it... :)  Thanks.

Comment: The first link is a full copy of the story as hosted on the author's website FWIW. :)